# Using homebrew how can I install multiple versions of the same software?

Tags: macos, unix, homebrew

I'm using OSX and homebrew. I need two versions of the same software. In my case I'd like to install vim that's built with the flag `--without-python --with-python3`, and vim built without those flags.

How can I do this with homebrew?

It would be really good if I could alias them to something like `vimpy2`, and `vimpy3` when I need to be choosy.

Comment: Does homebrew have a support site or a listserv?